# Who invented the Autobots and Decepticons?

Tags: transformers

The transformers are all sentient mechanical beings. Who invented them?

All mechanical life needs to be invented by biological beings, so who are their inventors?

Are the transformers actually alive? Are they bio-mechanical?

Comment: i'd always thought they evoled on their own. life from other planets could take on any number of properties imagined and an infinite number of unimagined ones.

Comment: Why does mechanical life need to be created by biological life? Not seeing that at all. (Unless, of course, each one comes with a "read me first" manual.)

Comment: The chicken!  Unless it was the egg...

Comment: @neilfein because mechanical lifeisnt alive, so SOMETHING had to give it sentience.

Comment: @OghmaOsiris Perhaps we should move this to chat.FutileArguments.SE? :)

Comment: @neilfein agreed :)

Comment: In *Transformers Armada* cartoon, it was displayed that both Autobots and Decepticons were being formed from the body of Unicorn, a god like digital creature.. Actually, a god.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the Generation 1 continuity, the Autobots and Decepticons were created by the **Quintessons**.

From the [*Transformers Wikia*](http://transformers.wikia.com/wiki/Quintesson):

> In ages long past, a cold and emotionless race of aliens called the Quintessons created two lines of sentient robots on a planet-sized factory known as Cybertron. One was a line of robots designed for domestic duties and labor (known as Autobots), and the other was a line designed for military use, (known as Decepticons). The Quintessons were exceptionally cruel to their creations, eventually leading to wide-spread rebellion, a rebellion started by the Autobot A3. Forced to flee the planet, the Quintessons eventually settled on the small, twisted planet of Quintessa, but fostered an undying hatred of all Transformers for millions of years.
>
> *Transformers Generation 1, Season 3 (1986), Five Faces of Darkness, Part 4*

Comment: Oh, yea, I'd forgotten about that line of cartoons after the movie.  I need to go back and watch those all again.

Answer (score 11):

The only canon I am aware of is from a segment of the comic books that talks about two god-like brothers, Primus and Unicron.  Primus was a noble, robotic warrior and Unicron, his brother was a destroyer of worlds.  Primus decided that he needed help fighting against Unicron and so he created a race of mechanical warriors to aid him in the struggle.  He then converted his asteroid home into a metallic world, thus giving birth to Cybertron.  He then went to sleep at the core of Cybertron.  The warriors became known as the Autobots.  Unicron was later able to turn some of them to his side, thus creating the Decepticons.

Comment: FWIW, this explanation is incompatible with the G1 cartoons. There, Unicron was created by a separate being ("Call of the Primitives") and Primus didn't exist at all.

Comment: True.  as @rems pointed out in G1 they were created by the Quintessons.  The problem with Transformers is they keep reinventing the story and changing it each time.